# How can I figure out how much memory a .Net Appdomain is consuming?

Tags: .net, clr

I'm trying to programmatically restrict the memory consumption of plugins running in a .Net AppDomain, but I can't find any setup parameters for this, nor can I find a way to query an AppDomain to figure out how much memory it is consuming. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the documentation for querying a process's memory usage. Not the same as the AppDomain, but it might be a place to start.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s80a75e5(VS.80).aspx

You can ask the GC what it thinks is currently allocated also.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 6):

Old question, but in the meantime (since .Net framework 4.0) a new solution is available. You will have to enable ARM (Application domain Resource Monitoring). From that point on, you can request information on total consumed processor time, memory usage etc.

[See Microsoft documentation over here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997285%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure programatically, but [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) can tell you how much memory a .net AppDomain is using.  Maybe they have some documentation out there about how they are querying that info.

Answer (score 0):

Using the mscoree.CorRuntimeHostClass interop from C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vXXXXXX\mscoree.tlb